# Configuring Opencart from testing to live?

Tags: php, opencart, hosting

I have changed the config file of both the root folder and /admin folder

```
<?php
// HTTP
    define('HTTP_SERVER', 'http://livesite.com/new/');

// HTTPS
    define('HTTPS_SERVER', 'http://livesite.com/new/');

// DIR
    define('DIR_APPLICATION', 'http://livesite.com/new/catalog/');
    define('DIR_SYSTEM', 'http://livesite.com/new/system/');
    define('DIR_IMAGE', 'http://livesite.com/new/image/');
    define('DIR_LANGUAGE', 'http://livesite.com/new/catalog/language/');
    define('DIR_TEMPLATE', 'http://livesite.com/new/catalog/view/theme/');
    define('DIR_CONFIG', 'http://livesite.com/new/system/config/');
    define('DIR_CACHE', 'http://livesite.com/new/system/storage/cache/');
    define('DIR_DOWNLOAD', 'http://livesite.com/new/system/storage/download/');
    define('DIR_LOGS', 'http://livesite.com/new/system/storage/logs/');
    define('DIR_MODIFICATION', 'http://livesite.com/new/system/storage/modification/');
    define('DIR_UPLOAD', 'http://livesite.com/new/system/storage/upload/');

// DB
    define('DB_DRIVER', 'mysqli');
    define('DB_HOSTNAME', 'localhost');
    define('DB_USERNAME', 'livesite');
    define('DB_PASSWORD', 'livesite');
    define('DB_DATABASE', 'livesite');
    define('DB_PORT', '3306');
    define('DB_PREFIX', 'livesite_');
?>
```

I am trying to host it on a subfolder of the site say "New" but when I go to livesite.com/new
I am being greeted with a blank screen

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use absolute paths for your configuration file. If you do not know your absolute path create a PHP file (for example called `path.php`) and add the following code to it.

```
<?php
$path = getcwd();
echo "This Is Your Absolute Path: ". $path . "<br>";
?>
```

Thereafter navigate to it in your browser `http://livesite.com/path.php`

Your absolute path should look something like: `/home/{prefix}/public_html/new` , remember the use of forward slashes instead of back slashes. 
**For security reasons remove the file once you completed with it.**